# Traversing $("body") except certain tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am traversing a page adding `<a href="tel:"></a>`using jquery to certain regex pattern I have for phone numbers. I am successfully traversing the page with `$("body:first").html()` but, I want to exclude some tags like: `<img>` `<scripts></script>` since they tend to break the page if they match a certain pattern I have in my regex.

I tried: `$("body:first").not("script").not("img").html();` with no success. I am running into elements that have pieces of content I am not interested in. Is there something I am missing? I log out my

Is there anyway to chain multiples of these using .not()?

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/552428/

Comment: its not a good start to parse html with regex, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a replace with regex over all of the HTML content is not the best idea, also traversing all of the potential candidate nodes with jQuery can be quite costly. As far as i understand your question, you want to replace phone numbers only within DOM textNodes - for this case all of the modern browsers have a native and performant `TreeWalker` - you can configure it to walk only through textNodes and do some additional fine-tuning with a filter method.

In your case that means getting all textNodes which do not reside within `script`, `style` and `svg` tags. Also `a` tags should be ignored since nested anchors are not valid. First we have to collect all of the matching textnodes, then regex-replace the content of their parentNode.

In my example i worked with `.innerHTML` (unsafe) and `.replaceWith` of the matching textNode, but done properly, we should change the regex in a fashion that we can work with `while(regex.exec(text))` to iterate over the matches and append textNodes as well anchor tags to its parentNode (after resetting its content to null).

```js
var phoneRegex = /(\b)((\+?[ ]?1?\(?)([\s ]?[\s-]?[\s.]?[\s ]?)(\(?[2-9]\d{2}\)?)([\s ]?[\s-]?[\s.]?[\s ]?)([2-9]\d{2}?)([\s ]?[\s-]?[\s.]?[\s ]?)(\d{4}\)?))(\b)/,
    // These node types can have TextNode children but we filter them out
    excludeNodes = ['SCRIPT', 'STYLE', 'SVG', 'A'],
    // Create a native treeWalker instance, seeking only text nodes
    // but ignore node types within excludeNodes and content which 
    // is not matching your regex
    treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
      acceptNode: function(node) {
        if(excludeNodes.indexOf(node.parentNode.nodeName.toUpperCase()) > -1
          || !phoneRegex.test(node.data)) return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
      }
    }),
    textNodes = [];

// Collect all matching text nodes (We can't do a live replacement of
// the nodes, otherwise the treewalker will break)
while(treeWalker.nextNode()) textNodes.push(treeWalker.currentNode);

// Replace all matching text nodes with a span if they match the phone regex
// and substitute the phone numbers with a surrounding <a> tag
//
// Note that the usage of .innerHTML is potentially unsafe, you could
// make this more secure by constructing textnodes and anchors and
// appending them to their parent
textNodes.forEach(function(textNode) {
  var newNode = document.createElement('span');
  newNode.innerHTML = textNode.textContent.replace(phoneRegex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");
  textNode.replaceWith(newNode);
});
```

```html
<p>1-888-452-1505</p>

<p>1(408)5625504</p>

<p><a href="mailto:some@bo.dy">1(408)5625504</a></p>

<p>1.408.562.5504</p>

<p>1-613-3568772</p>

<p>(1)9543615599</p>

<p>1.954.361.5599</p>

<p>+1.954.361.5599</p>

<p>954.361.5599</p>

<p>+1 954 361-5599</p>

<p>(954) 361-5599</p>

<p>(954)361-5599</p>

<p>9543615599</p>

<p>(954)3615599</p>

<p>+19543615599</p>
 
<p>1-954-361-5599</p>

<p>+1-954-361-5599</p>

<p>954 361-5599</p>

<p>Prefix Text +1-954-361-5599</p>

<p>+1-954-361-5599 Post Text</p>

<div>
  Nested items
  <ul>
    <li>954 361-5599</li>
  </ul>
  <p>(954)3615599</p>
</div>
<script>console.log("ignore me please (954)3615599")</script>
<svg>Some svg data, ignore phone numbers like +1-954-361-5599 etc.</svg>
```

Comment: This treewalker object is all foreign to me. NICE ANSWER! I was noticing some performance issues within the jquery traversing. If someone hits a toggle to "off" how difficult of an implementation would it be to reverse the whole treewalking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, although you don't want to grab just body, you want all the elements in body.

Try something like the following:

```js
var elements = $('body *').not('script').not('span').get(0);

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This works but it only gives me first element I need all so I can then look for any phone numbers un-formatted and add the <a href="tel:"> around them </a>

Comment: Please provide some sample data, and what you're expected result should be.

Comment: Here is an example of it working with regular trags. I just don't want it to look for <script>, <svg>, <img>, amongst others. I'm thinking maybe a variable that contains all my ignores. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/552428/

Answer (score 0):

[I forked your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94p5Lgr7/) and got it working with your regex and replacing each applicable text node

```
const phoneRegex = /555-555-5555/
const phoneMarkup = "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>"
const hyperlink = text => text.replace(phoneRegex, phoneMarkup)

$("body :not(:empty):not(script):not(img):not(svg)")
  .contents()
  .each(function() {
    if (3 !== this.nodeType) return
    const text = this.textContent
    if (!text) return
    const markup = hyperlink(text)
    if (markup === text) return
    $(this).replaceWith(markup)
  })
```

- Select via [CSS3+ `:not`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#negation) chaining **or** via jQuery [`.not`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) with commas

  - `$("body :not(:empty):not(script):not(img):not(svg)")`
  - `$("body :not(:empty)").not("script,img,svg")`
- Iterate [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

  1. Skip non-text nodes
  2. Read text via [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
  3. Skip empty nodes
  4. Hyperlink text using your regex replace
  5. Avoid excess DOM manipulation
  6. Replace text node via [`.replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to go about this is to store the tags you want to ignore in an array and use [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) to get a comma-separated value of its contents. Since [`jQuery.fn.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) supports passing multiple selectors separated by commas, this will work as desired.

Also, be sure to use the `body *` selector to select all the descendants of the body, because the one you use currently only selects the `body` element.

After fetching all desired elements, you can iterate over them and execute your regular expression on each of them and update their [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) with their [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) after replacing the appropriate parts.

**Example:**

```js
/* ------ JavaScript ----- */
const regex = /(\b)((\+?[ ]?1?\(?)([\s ]?[\s-]?[\s.]?[\s ]?)(\(?[2-9]\d{2}\)?)([\s ]?[\s-]?[\s.]?[\s ]?)([2-9]\d{2}?)([\s ]?[\s-]?[\s.]?[\s ]?)(\d{4}\)?))(\b)/;
const ignoredTags = ["script", "svg", "img"];
const wantedElements = $("body *").not(ignoredTags.toString());

wantedElements.each(function (index, element) {
  element.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1-888-452-1505</p>
<p>1(408)5625504</p>
<p>1.408.562.5504</p>
<p>1-613-3568772</p>
<p>Prefix Text +1-954-361-5599</p>
<p>+1-954-361-5599 Post Text</p>
<script>console.log("ignore me please")</script>
<svg></svg>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
```